# Assign values to a text field based on a buttons text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am creating a program that takes an input file, parses that information and builds a GUI calculator from that information. Currently the program works well except for when I implement an ActionListener on buttons that should set a text field to the value of the buttons getText() method.

I have tried a few different loop constructions using for and while, but all of them I have implemented have not found the where i or a counter is equal to the parsed int from numPad.getText() or returned 0 for all of the buttons.

The problem I am having while testing is that the variable i never matches numPoint. Logically my approach is to decrement i so that the loop will continue to look for matches, but never does this. The test output statements infinite loop "-1" for i and "7" for numPoint. As a note, the numPad array is not in order but instead the elements are as follows {7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0}.

I realize that this loop may not be logically correct, but I am having a hard time finding a solution that works. I want to avoid hard coding if statements (such as `i == Integer(parseInt.numPad[0].getText()`) which would work.

This is the loop that creates the new buttons and adds them to an Array, sets the text based on a list created from the values of the input file and adds an ActionListener.

```
for (int i = 0; i < run.buttons.size(); i++) {
        numPad[i] = new JButton();
        numPad[i].setText(run.buttons.get(i));
        numPad[i].addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
        panel1.add(numPad[i]);
    }
```

This is the most recent attempt at creating a loop that should make the assignment.

```
public static class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int i;
        int numPoint;
        for (i = 0; i < numPad.length; i++) {
            numPoint = Integer.parseInt(numPad[i].getText());

            if (i == numPoint) {
                //Match, assign
                System.out.println("works");
                break;
            } else {
                //Decrement and continue
                i--;
                System.out.println("test statement" + i + " " + numPoint);
                continue;
            }
        }

    }       
}
```

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you might do this, but let's start with the basics

```
for (int i = 0; i < run.buttons.size(); i++) {
        numPad[i] = new JButton();
        numPad[i].setText(run.buttons.get(i));
        // You don't "have" to do this, as the action command defaults
        // to the text of the button, but this is away to provide some
        // kind of identifier to the action which might be
        // different from the text
        numPad[i].setActionCommand(run.buttons.get(i))
        numPad[i].addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener());
        panel1.add(numPad[i]);
}
```

Then in your `ActionListener`...

```
public static class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        int numPoint = Integer.parseInt(command);
        // Perform what ever action you need
    }
```